# JQuery mask apenas alfabético com comportamento estranho

Tags: jquery, jquery-masked-input

Estou tentando adicionar uma máscara em um campo para aceitar apenas caracteres alfabéticos.

Aparentemente consegui encontrar uma [solução](https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/10/restricting-input-with-jquery/?fbclid=IwAR0BKELaOzUYxVDmA8R2pnXdtDiVRMasqvKJKndArJqkmQojL_nJ6MC-9Uk).

**Código**

```
$(function () {

    $("#name").keypress( function(key) {

        if((key.charCode < 97 || key.charCode > 122) && (key.charCode < 65 || key.charCode > 90) && key.charCode != 32 ) {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Até aí funciona legal, aceita apenas letras(`[a-zA-Z]`) e `espaço` apenas.

Mas o bizarro que depois de inserir qualquer sequência de letras, depois de dar `espaço` duas vezes aparece um `ponto` do nada.

Se eu tento proibir explicitamente a permissão do `ponto` incluindo `key.charCode == 46` no `if` buga tudo e passa a aceitar qualquer tipo de caractere.

[image: Imagem com o bug]

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer funcionar corretamente?

Comment: Essa condição nunca será atendida: `key.charCode < 65 && key.charCode > 90` acho que aqui você queria utilizar o *ou* `||`

Comment: Verdade, botei errado e não vi

Comment: eu só digitei errado mesmo, tava olhando na tela de um pc e digitando em outro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mas o que você está fazendo com esse eventListener? Você só está retornando false caso o caractere não seja o que você quer, o que isso significa?

Não há o que analisar no código, o código postado nem sequer é uma mascara. Se você quer fazer uma mascara para letras e espaços, tente algo como:

```
$(function () {

    $("#name").on('input', function(e) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zà-ÿ\s]/ig, '');
    });

});
```